# How to create SQL query to sort JSON array using 1 attribute?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, sql-order-by, lateral-join

I have a table with a column that contains a JSON body that has arrays that I want to sort based on a attribute associated with that array.

I have tried selecting the array name and displaying the attribute which will display the entire array

The column name is `my_column` and the JSON is formatted as follows -

```
{
    "num": "123",
    "Y/N": "Y",
    "array1":[
         {
             "name": "Bob",
             "sortNum": 123
         },
         {
             "name": "Tim Horton",
             "sortNum": 456
         }
    ]
}
```

I want the output to be based on the highest value of `sortNum` so the query should display the attributes for Tim Horton. The code I have played around with is below but get an error when trying to query based on sortNum.

```
SELECT my_column 
FROM 
    my_table,
    jsonb_array_elements(my_column->'array1') elem
WHERE elem->>'sortNum' = INT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Order by the filed `'sortNum'` of the array element descending and use `LIMIT 1` to only get the top record.

```
SELECT jae.e
       FROM my_table t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.my_column->'array1') jae (e)
       ORDER BY jae.e->'sortNum' DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

---

Edit:

If you want to sort numerically rather than lexicographically, get the element as text and cast it to an integer prior sorting on it.

```
SELECT jae.e
       FROM my_table t
            CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(t.my_column->'array1') jae (e)
       ORDER BY (jae.e->>'sortNum')::integer DESC
       LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that your table has a column (or maybe a combination of columns) that can be use to uniquely identify a record. Let's call it `myid`.

To start with, we can use `json_array_elements` to split the JSON array into rows, as follows:

```
select myid, x.value, x->>'sortNum' 
from 
    mytable, 
    json_array_elements(mycolumn->'array1') x
;
```

This returns:

```
myid  |  value                                 | sortnum
---------------------------------------------------------
1     |   {"name":"Bob","sortNum":123}         | 123
1     |   {"name":"Tim Horton","sortNum":456}  | 456
```

Now, we can turn this to a subquery, and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to filter in the array element with the highest `sortNum` attribute:

```
select value
from (
    select 
        x.value, 
        row_number() over(partition by myid order by x->>'sortNum' desc) rn
    from 
        mytable, 
        json_array_elements(mycolumn->'array1') x
) y 
where rn = 1;
```

Yields:

```
value
-----------------------------------
{"name":"Tim Horton","sortNum":456}
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4WjrsdZRztu7kcXEiPrSGh/1)**